# RethinkDB: Get only one record from cursor/selection

Tags: rethinkdb, reql

If I have a query that returns multiple results, how do I get a single element from the selection?

e.g.

```
r.db("test").table("things") // returns an array of things. I want one of them
```

Using `limit(1)` is not what I want because that returns an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rethink DB supports getting the [nth element](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/#nth) so the query should be:

```
r.db("test").table("things").nth(0)
```

In the event that there are no elements, the above will fail with:

> Index out of bounds: 0

The solution to this is to return a default object (null in my case) if no element exists.

```
r.db("test").table("things").nth(0).default(null)
```